# Scrollview not working in this XML file in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

This doesn't works for my login when I click on edittext for entering password or username, I want to get items scrolled when virtual/ soft keyboard is open.

I have also tried to put Scrollview as parent tag and then LinearLayout tag but the contents starts from top only, while I want the contents in the center because there is my background with login logo.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/login"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:hint="Email Address"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColorHint="#c3c3c3"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/black_underline"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_phone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:hint="Phone Number"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColorHint="#c3c3c3"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:maxLength="10"
                        android:background="@drawable/black_underline"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#000"

                        />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_otp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="#449284"
                        android:text="Generate OTP Password"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_otp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:hint="OTP Password"
                        android:background="@drawable/black_underline"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColorHint="#c3c3c3"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#000"

                        />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="#449284"
                        android:text="Submit"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        />


                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add

```
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in manifest for that particular activity . and add this attribute to the `ScrollView`

```
    android:fillViewport="true"
```

and if your using this line

```
  android:windowTranslucentStatus=true
```

in theme means just remove that.

Comment: I tried this one and in my style.xml I also not used `android:windowTranslucentStatus=true` anywhere but scrollview don't work ... can you try this on your side and send me code ?

Comment: its working perfectly for me @Chintak . atom.ananthababu@gmail.com send me invite request

Comment: Hello,
I had problem in java, that I put in java file

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

As I removed it, it started **BUT** it takes whole screen resize and all contents goes up on. 

I want it to be in centered and when I scroll from my hand, it should scroll

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ScrollView`, then it has to be the parent. You can then use a `RelativeLayout` as parent to position elements as per your requirement.
You can also try setting `android:fillViewport="true"` in the ScrollView.

If you cannot have `ScrollView` as the parent, consider using `NestedScrollView` instead.

Comment: I tried both but it doesn't work... can you check it at your side and send me code

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

add this line to particular activity in Manifest.